# Using GIT in atom for local development

Tags: git, version-control, localhost, atom-editor, git-revert

I´ve educated myself a little about git, since it´s integrated in atom and therefore I can easily revert commits I did without having to do backups of my code all the time (If I understood GIT correctly).
Most of these tutorials about GIT also talk about Github, where you can then publish your master branch. But I´d like to develop everything locally, not publishing anything. Therefore, github is not an option. I want to only use GIT.
In Atom, the only way to revert commits you have done is by following the PUSH and PULL workflow as a github user. Since I´m not signed in to github in atom, I am not able to do anything more than initialize git in a directory, "stage" specific files/changes and commit them.
I´ve also downloaded git from the official webpage and configured it in cmd. How am I able to revert commits locally (via atom)?

Comment: @phd But can I accomplish this without using the command line? Is there a option for this in atom?

Comment: @phd Changed the question accordingly. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> via atom or a command-line-interface

I will show you two command-line-interface options.

Let's start out in a new repository.

```
$ mkdir how_to_undo_stuff_in_git
$ cd how_to_undo_stuff_in_git
$ git init # Initialize git (only needed once)
```

First, we'll create one file, `myfile`, with the content `foo`.

```
$ echo foo > myfile
$ git add myfile
$ git commit -m "Add foo content"
```

Next, we are going to apply a second commit that we want to undo.

```
$ echo bar >> myfile
$ git add bar
$ git commit -m "Add bar content (bad commit)"
```

## Using 'revert'

The `git revert` command can "cancel out" a commit for you.  It does it by applying a new commit that, well, reverts your changes.

Simply run

```
$ git revert HEAD
```

You can now inspect the `myfile` contents and see that the "bar" string disappeared.  You can also run `git log` and it should look like this

```
Author: Alan Turing <alan@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 9 15:28:51 2019 +0000

    Revert "bar content"

    This reverts commit bc483fc6fd069c70f6822a8b840f74ced64d32c8.

commit bc483fc6fd069c70f6822a8b840f74ced64d32c8
Author: Alan Turing <alan@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 9 15:28:35 2019 +0000

    bar content

commit f6450431be631220210eb83c152d907058a6337d
Author: Alan Turing <alan@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 9 15:27:23 2019 +0000

    foo content
```

## Using 'reset' (be careful!)

`git` also offers the option to really "erase" a commit, as opposed to creating a new commit that cancels a prior commit.  Be careful when running `git reset` because you can really loose parts of your work when you accidentally supply wrong arguments to it.  Taken from: https://ohshitgit.com/#accidental-commit-master

```
$ git reset HEAD~ --hard
```

This will erase the last commit.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to do this in the atom UI?

Comment: hm .... I just installed `atom` and tried to find it out.  Unfortunately I didn't manage to do it via the atom UI.

Answer (score 0):

One of the challenges here is that beyond the basic functions git almost always requires the use of the command line. I for one don't mind too much, as it forces you to learn more about what each function does specifically, and several git functions can wreak havoc on a repository if misused. So long story short, if you're going to be using git extensively, you may want to get comfortable with the command-line sooner rather than later.

Addressing your question more directly:
When undoing one (or more) commits, the typical solution would be to use `git revert` or `git reset` to overwrite/rollback the commit. (See Matt's answer for more on those two commands)

Looking at the comments, however, it looks like you are looking for a way to do this that is built right into Atom. Luckily it looks like the github package does include an **undo** button. It's located in the commit history in the bottom right of the git panel. From using it once or twice, it looks like it resets to the previous commit, while also keeping and staging the changes from the "undone" commit. This seems to be what you want. Be careful, however, if ever using this on a commit you have already pushed to remote. You will probably need to merge any further changes, and resetting the remote commit as well (while possible) is highly discouraged.

If you were asking more generally (beyond `git revert`/`git remove`) then you have a couple of extra options:

For one, you have packages like [git-plus](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus) and [git-control](https://atom.io/packages/git-control) that implement additional git functions into Atom. git-plus doesn't require you to open a terminal, but it seems to require a basic understanding of how the functions work and what parameters are required.

Additionally, if you decide that you'd like to start using the command-line, there are packages that implement a terminal right in Atom. [This](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) is the one I use. This is the only way I know of to be able to use git to the extent of its capacity directly from within Atom.